# Scan folder in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I like the JavaScript equivalence of the PHP function:

```
echo json_encode(glob("images/*.jpg")) ?>);
```

is it possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't scan a filesystem with javascript. If your site has empty directory indexing, you can  parse the resulting html, and pull out a list of links to images.

In general, you are **much** better off just putting that php snippet in a file and calling it from javascript.

Comment: done it in php... work great... sometimes you have to take the right tool for the right work !

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does not in any way/shape/form directly support file-based I/O, including reading directory contents.